# React Native on Android - ScrollView with pictures has terrible performance

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

On iOS, ScrollView (horizontal) works but when on Android the ScrollView is terribly slow and unusable.

I get this error many times:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 240 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

If I take off my images within the ScrollView, it works fine but kind of need this images.

Thanks!

Comment: Really hard to say without seeing any of your code.

Comment: Figured it out. The image sizes were just way to big.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the image sizes worked for me.

Comment: Do you remember some details about the image sizes that caused your frame drops? I have similar poor performance, and rendering ~15-20 1.5 MB images at once.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try to add all images to drawable-nodpi folder. It worked for me